# JQuery Add / Subtract value from input inside the li where the button was clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a unordered list.
Each has 2 buttons and one input.
One button would add the current value of the input and the other would subtract.

As there would be more that 1

Here's the html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <button class="add">Add</button>
        <input type="text" value="0" />
        <button class="subtract">Subtract</button>
    </li>

    <li>
        <button class="add">Add</button>
        <input type="text" value="0" />
        <button class="subtract">Subtract</button>
    </li>

</ul>
```

How could I use JQuery for each

values to be independent?

Comment: So if they start at `0` - how does adding and subtracting work? And start with simple event handlers and using `this`

Comment: It won't be important if it display's minus fiqures.

Comment: Where did you get stuck when you tried to implement this yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
$('.add').click(function() { 
   var $input = $(this).next();
   var currentValue = parseInt($input.val());
   $input.val(currentValue + 1);
});

$('.subtract').click(function() { 
   var $input = $(this).prev();
   var currentValue = parseInt($input.val());
   $input.val(currentValue - 1);
});
```

Comment: It's almost there. 1 problem. It's not replacing the input value just adding 1's to the end of the current one

Comment: Missed `parseInt()` to convert value to number. Please try again

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

    $(".add,.subtract").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).hasClass("add")){

            var val = parseInt($(this).parents("li").find("[type='text']").val()) +1;
            $(this).parents("li").find("[type='text']").val( val );

        }else{

            var val = parseInt($(this).parents("li").find("[type='text']").val()) -1;
            $(this).parents("li").find("[type='text']").val( val );

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using, as this is based on 2.x?

Answer (score 1):

One approach, using jQuery is the following:

```
// selecting the <li> elements,
// binding an anonymous event-handler for the 'click' event,
// when that event is fired on the '.add' or '.subtract' elements:
$('li').on('click', '.add, .subtract', function(e) {

  // caching a reference to the clicked element:
  var clicked = this;

  // finding the sibling <input> element(s) of the clicked element,
  // updating its value, via the val() method:
  $(this).siblings('input').val(function(i, v) {
    // i, is the index of the current element in the collection
    // v, is the current value - before we adjust it.

    // we convert the value-string 'v' into a base-ten number,
    // using parseInt(), and add either 1 or -1 to that number;
    // if the clicked element's classList contains the class-name
    // of 'add', we add the 1; otherwise we add a -1;
    // and return the result of that calculation:
    return parseInt(v, 10) + (clicked.classList.contains('add') ? 1 : -1);
  });
});
```

```js
$('li').on('click', '.add, .subtract', function(e) {
  var clicked = this;
  $(this).siblings('input').val(function(i, v) {
    return parseInt(v, 10) + (clicked.classList.contains('add') ? 1 : -1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="add">Add</button>
    <input type="text" value="0" />
    <button class="subtract">Subtract</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="add">Add</button>
    <input type="text" value="0" />
    <button class="subtract">Subtract</button>
  </li>

</ul>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [Conditional (Ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).